# Creating unique records based on field values

Tags: apex, date

There are 2 objects say, Object1 and Object2 both having 2 fields each, say City(Text) and BatchDate(Date). Object1 records get created through integration with external system and Object2 records get created based on Object1 records creation.

[image]

As seen from the above, Object1 records created through Integration can contain duplicate BatchDates per City. For eg. City A can have same batchdate. Once Object1 records are created, Object2 records need to be created in such a way that each City can have unique Batch Dates as seen above. If Object1 records are CityA-1/1/2017, CityA-1/1/2017, CityA-1/1/2017, CityB-1/1/2017 and CityB-1/1/2017 then Object2 records that should get created are CityA-1/1/2017 and CityB-1/1/2017. I tried taking all Object1 batchDates in a Set and tried to create Object2 only for those batchDates but realised that Batchdates must be unique per City. Can you please let me know how to proceed with the logic for this scenario/functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to enforce this is to create a composite key. This is done in a few easy steps. First, create a new text field, and mark it as unique. Second, create a workflow rule that always fires, and sets the value of the field to City+Date as a text value. Third, update all existing records in the database so that the unique values are populated. At this point, the database will maintain uniqueness for you; your external system will receive errors if it tries to create duplicate entries.

If you want to insert and update based on this composite key, you can calculate the unique value on the external system, and mark the field as an External ID instead. From there, you can use the upsert API call to insert or update based on the contents of the custom field. This will allow the external system to update records instead of getting errors back.